# How to remove deprecated AWS queues/topics created by MassTransit?

Tags: amazon-sqs, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit AmazonSQS and I would want to know if there is any way of removing/deleting the queues and the topics that got created by MassTransit,for which there is no more need to exist, like when the message is renamed or when there are no more messages being published to that queue. Are there some attributes to set on the topic/queue so that after a certain period of inactivity the AWS resources created by MassTransit are removed automatically?

I am aware of the "AutoDelete" configuration property, but I use it with temporary queues and these get removed successfully, but in the case of a durable queue, how do we ensure the resources are removed when they're not in use after a certain period (both AWS topics and queues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit will not remove any topics, subscriptions, or queues. It will only create missing entities.

It is your responsibility to remove any topics, subscriptions, or queues that are no longer in use. From a *code* perspective, if a queue isn't being used, MassTransit probably doesn't know about it anyway.

Comment: So, most likely, I'd need an additional tool to do this programmatically, was hoping there is some functionality I might not be aware of, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's about managing risk. People might be annoyed if you create a queue they didn't expect, but they'll be raging-angry if you delete a queue full of production data after they removed a consumer for testing.