# Azure Service Bus automatic queue delete

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I am using MassTransit along with Azure Service Bus.

All consumers APIs automatically create queues in ASB, but if a consumer is removed **the queue stays.**

Even worse, if the message type that was used for the removed consumer still exists and is being used throughout the system (for other consumers), the old queue still accepts and hoards messages.

**An example would be:**
Consumer 'A' accepts messages of type 'mA'.
Consumer 'B' also accepts messages of type 'mA'.

For both of these, a queue is created in ASB (Queue A and Queue B).

Now because of some changes, Consumer 'A' is no longer needed and is deleted from the API - but if message 'mA' is published, both Queue A and Queue B will still receive it.

An obvious solution would be to just have a pretty low **Auto-delete** setting, but this will only remove the unneeded messages, not the queues themselves.

Comment: You have to delete the queue on your own. How do you tell, if the consumer does no longer want to consume messages or if there's an outage at the consumer's side?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer Thanks. Ideally I would've hoped for something that deletes the queue if there are no outgoing messages for a fixed period.

Comment: well, you can automate this with Azure Function and Timertrigger.

Comment: [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72478917/how-to-remove-deprecated-aws-queues-topics-created-by-masstransit) but for SQS, same answer.